# TSQL Parse single column into multiple columns/rows without a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to query a ticketing system, where multiple users can be assigned to a ticket at once.

It stores the assignees as comma-delimited values in a column `AH.AssignedTo_ETrack_UserID`.

For example: `429173,525304,390497`

When I try to run the following, the `JOIN` fails because of the comma.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(RI.ID) as REQ_NUM
    ,HT.FullName
FROM 
    RequestInfo RI
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RequestAssignInfoHistory AH ON RI.ID = AH.RequestInfo_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    WA_Team HT ON AH.AssignedTo_ETrack_UserID = HT.ID
```

Error message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '429173,525304,390497' to data type int.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

I only have READ rights to this system, so I can't create a function.

Comment: It would be far better if you could change the design and use one of the data types that SQL Server supports for actually storing multiple items - which would be XML or a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table Comma(commaValue varchar(50))
go
insert into Comma Values('429173,525304,390497')
insert into Comma Values('429173,525304,390497')

;WITH Split_Requests (xmlname)
AS
(
    SELECT 
    CONVERT(XML,'<Requests><Request>'  
    + REPLACE(commaValue,',', '</Request><Request>') + '</Request></Requests>') AS xmlname
      FROM Comma
)

SELECT 
xmlname.value('/Requests[1]/Request[1]','varchar(25)') AS [Type1],
xmlname.value('/Requests[1]/Request[2]','varchar(25)') AS [Type2],
xmlname.value('/Requests[1]/Request[3]','varchar(25)') AS [Type3]
FROM Split_Requests
```

Now you can use this table in your query and apply join. Please also check
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7206a/1

Comment: thanks!  One follow-up question..  I found this field can have 6 assignees.  How would I modify the statement to do accommodate this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing will change, only you need to add logic for getting extra request value. Like Request[4]....

Comment: I tried that, but ran into problems with the Convert statement.

  `  SELECT 
        CONVERT(XML,'<Requests><Request>'  
        + REPLACE(commaValue,',', '</Request><Request>')     + '</Request></Requests>') AS xmlname
          FROM Comma`

I couldn't it to work.

Comment: No you don't need to change anything there. I think the problem in sqlfiddle. You can check it with sqlserver. It should work fine there.